# how am i supposed to pull a record from DAO vector?

Tags: sql, database, swing, jframe, dao

I'm trying to implement the login page based on Oracle sql using JFrame(swing). I already have inserted IDs and PWs on database. Plus, I've also already defined appropriate -I think- LoginMember method in DAO. Below are the codes for Jframe page and DAO. Please let me know what is wrong with this. I've been struggling with this for the last 5 hours and still have no idea what to do.. HELP!! Sorry if you feel that I have not given enough info to solve this problem.

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String strID=tfID.getText();
            String strPW=String.valueOf(pwfPW.getPassword());

            if(tfID.getText().equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Login.this, "Please type your ID");
            } else {
                dao=new M_DAO();
                dao.loginMember(strID,strPW);
                if(tfID.getText().equals(dao.loginMember(strID,strPW))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Login.this, strID+" : successfully logged in");                   
                }else if(strID ==null && strID.equals(strPW)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Login.this, "Incorrect ID or PW.");
                }else{
                    System.out.println(10);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

DAO:

```
public Vector loginMember(String strID,String strPW) {
    Vector items=new Vector();
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try {
        conn=DB.hrConn();
        String sql="select * from member where strID=? and strPW=?";
        pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, "strID");
        pstmt.setString(2, "strPW");
        rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            Vector row=new Vector();
            row.add("strID");
            row.add("strPW");
            items.add(row);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(rs!=null) rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if(pstmt!=null) pstmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if(conn!=null) conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

I wish it would work so bad...

It only shows the correct answer when I type nothing on ID and PW textfields, saying "Please type your ID". It prints out 10 when I type something on those.(just to check which line has an error.) Oh, please let me know if I need to specify something else!

Comment: `if(tfID.getText().equals(dao.loginMember(strID,strPW)))`: how could a String be equal to a Vecor? That makes no sense. `if(strID ==null && strID.equals(strPW))`: how could a variable be null and be equal to another String at the same time? That makes no sense either. Please: 1 respect the Java naming conventions; 2. stop using Vector, which is obsolete since Java 2; 3. Use a class to represent a Member, instead of using a Vector; 4. think about what your methods are supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Now I get to know some of my errors one by one.